# Angular nested component's template not applied

Tags: angular, angular-components

This is my `yes-no.dialog.html`

```
<roi-dialog-content>
    {{ text }}
</roi-dialog-content>

<roi-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onValidate()">{{ yesText }}</button>
    <button mat-stroked-button (click)="onCancel()" cdkFocusInitial>{{ noText }}</button>
</roi-dialog-actions>
```

This is the `roi-dialog-content.component.html`

```
<mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-content>
    
    </ng-content>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

When the dialog is displayed, the `<mat-dialog-content>` is not rendered.

```
const yesno = this.dialog.open(DialogYesNoComponent, { data: { text: "this is some text", yesText: "Yes", noText: "No"}});
    
yesno.beforeClosed().subscribe((result: boolean) => {
    console.log('dialog result=', result);
});
```

[image]

How can I make the inner element `<mat-dialog-content>` rendered?

Comment: When you click mat-dialog then yesno.component is being rendered. Then what is your requirement ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda The requirement is that the inner component's template is applied and `<mat-dialog-content>` element that is part of the template is rendered into the page.

Comment: Which inner components do you want to set?

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Can You add full HTML of this ?

Comment: @GRD I found the cause of the issue. In my module for dialogs, I forgot to declare and export the `RoiDialogContentComponent` and `RoiDialogActionsComponent` components. I am new to Angular and It was a beginner's mistake.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik Glad! You found it out. My only one suggestion is try to look at SCAM pattern, Single Module with Single Component, This way you can get only those components that are needed by module, suppose You have 3 components in Shared module, and you need only one component to reuse to other module then by importing shared module you also impoted other components too, which were not required it by you. While in SCAM pattern its not the problem at all, angular material follow this. Thank You. And if you need any help or collaboration then connect with me by email `grdtechlab@gmail.com`